# Android : Error: Program type already present: com.google.common.base.AbstractIterator$State

Tags: java, gradle, google-api, android-gradle-plugin

I am using the Google Cloud Speech API to create an app and keep getting this error. I've previously excluded the guava-jdk5 library to take care of other similar errors. Any help on how to tackle this?

I've attached part of my App Gradle File here :-

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-speech:v1beta1-rev336-1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-language:v1beta2-rev6-1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:0.61.0-beta'
implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
    exclude module: 'guava-jdk5'
}
implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-tasks:v1-rev52-1.23.0') {
    exclude module: 'guava-jdk5'
}

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the same dependency but with a different version and excluded a module twice, no surprise.

Try removing:

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
```

And also, as researched about [`com.google.common.base.AbstractIterator$State`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/base/AbstractIterator.java) error, you excluded `guava-jdk5` **twice**.

So, change the dependencies as follows:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-speech:v1beta1-rev336-1.22.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-language:v1beta2-rev6-1.22.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:0.61.0-beta'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-tasks:v1-rev52-1.23.0'
    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
        exclude module: 'guava-jdk5'
    }
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Then try to rebuild.

<sub>I've also changed the `compile` to `implementation` since `compile` is depreciated.</sub>

Comment: What is causing this issue? I've been sitting with the Google API for a couple of weeks now and all of a sudden this becomes an issue...